# How to pass headers to uwsgi without using nginx?

Tags: python, http-headers, uwsgi

We were using nginx in front of uwsgi to pass the parameters to connexion framework. After removing nginx we are not able to get SSL authentication to work because we're missing X-Ssl-Client-Dn which we need to process a request using X.509 certificate authorization:

```
uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

uwsgi_param  SSL_CLIENT_DN  $ssl_client_s_dn;
uwsgi_param  SSL_CLIENT_SERIAL  $ssl_client_serial;
uwsgi_param  HTTP_X_SSL_CLIENT_DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
uwsgi_param  HTTP_X_REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
```

uwsgi is started with the following command:

```
    $UWSGI_PATH/uwsgi --uid restapi --gid www-data -s /tmp/restapi.sock --chmod-socket=660 --manage-script-name \
--chdir /home/restapi/${REST_API_REPO}/code_server/openapi_server --cache2 name=restapicache,items=2 \
--die-on-term --mount /=sbcs_main:app --pidfile $PIDFILE \
--logger syslog --buffer-size 32768 --enable-threads \
--disable-logging --log-4xx --log-5xx \
--strict --vacuum --single-interpreter \
--max-requests 10000 --max-worker-lifetime 3600 \
--cheaper-algo busyness --cheaper 4 --cheaper-initial 4 \
--workers 16 --cheaper-step 2 --cheaper-overload 15 \
--cheaper-busyness-backlog-alert 16 --cheaper-busyness-backlog-step 2 \
--http 0.0.0.0:1234 \
--ssl-verify-depth 2
--https 0.0.0.0:1235,my.crt,my.key,,HIGH,!ca.crt  &
```

This errors out with message  `unable to load configuration from 2`. If we remove `ssl-verify-depth` it starts OK. It may be related to missing headers issue.
Unable to figure out how to pass the headers in uwsgi.

Went through uwsgi docs but cannot find anything useful on the headers issue.

Comment: Got ssl-verify-depth working. It needs to be "=2" rather than just " 2". But that didn't fix the HTTP_X_SSL_CLIENT_DN problem.

Comment: Still cannot get  uwsgi web server to pass a certificate DN into Flask which eventually reaches our code. We are able to do this with NGINX using a uwsgi_param but don't know how to do this when using uwsgi as the web server.